# Level VAR stability for VECM estimation

Tags: vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I am trying to estimate VECM model for I(1) and cointegrated data. First, I try to find the optimal number of lags by using VARselect by following the below steps:

1. level data is given to VARselect,
2. optimal number of lags is chosen according to either AIC or BIC (or other statistical info criteria),
   (`VARselect(inputdata, lag.max = 10)$selection` in R)
3. residual autocorrelation is assessed with Lagrange Multiplier test,  (`serial.test(VAR_example, lags.pt= numberoflags, type="BG")` in R )
4. stability of VAR system is checked (`roots(VAR_example)` in R).

I do not have any problem with steps 1,2,3 but for most of the cases I find a root lying outside the unit circle so VAR does not satisfy stability condition.

Is this something expected since we start VARselect with level data or does this indicate a problem with optimal lag selection hence we can not use this number of optimal lag (given by VAR) in VECM estimation?

I appreciate  your help very much in advance.

Comment: @Richard Hardy. Reading your previous posts, most probably you are the most knowledgeable in this field. My question is a bit urgent. I will appreciate so much if you share your opinion with me. Many many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the answer right off the bat and I am quite busy nowadays. If I were you, I would look for the answer in econometric textbooks, e.g. Lutkepohl's "New Introduction to Multivariate Time Series Analysis" or the like.

Comment: @RichardHardy thanks so much. I will check immediately.